# UITabBarViewController Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am novice to iOS programming. I have created a public repository of the code at github the url of the repository is git@github.com:abhinavtyagi/paparazzi.git

I am facing a problem in using UITabBarController. The application have two tabs in the main view with each tabView containing a navigation controller.

The application consists of three views as follows (for each tabview)
 #1# first View shows the types of images (landscape, flowers, planets)
 #2# second view uses table view to list the images and their names.
 #3# when selected any cell in the previous(2nd) view, the image is shown in full screen in the next view.
This works fine if we use back buttons for the navigation. But the application crashes when we move to first view directly from  the third BY TAPPING THE TAB BAR TWICE when in third view(full screen pic).

I am not able to understand why its happening.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Abhinav

Comment: Post relevant sections of your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you tap on tab bar button twice.... it calls `viewDidLoad` of its `viewController`(in your case `rootViewController of navigationController`)....... may be this is causing the crash/ as everything will be reloaded.....

Comment: Hi,
I have solved the related issue. I was not holding the pointer to the navController and was the issue. Just had to associate the ivar while creation and while dealloc.

Thanks a lot